# phonegap gives the error of PhoneGapLib/Classes/Capture.m:743: error: 'NSEC_PER_MSEC' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

when i am creating a phonegap based application then it gives the error of "NSEC_PER_MSEC" undeclared and i doesn't get any idea to resolve this error can anyone help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of XCode are you using? What version of PhoneGap?

This seems to usually happen using XCode 3.2.5 instead of the latest version (3.2.6 at present).

Try upgrading your XCode, and perhaps even creating a new project directly in 3.2.6 and putting your assets in it and see if that solves the issue.